# Check if in a specific area

Tags: java, minecraft

**Re-edited the question to make more sense due to confusion

Imagine there is a coordinate plane with the dimensions:

X: 0-1000
Z: 0-1000

We divide the plane into ten regions like so:

Region 1:

X: 0-99
Z: 0-99

Region 2:

X: 100-199
Z: 100-199

and so on...

We then generate three random numbers, such as:

X: 56
Z: 38

**What would be the most efficient way to check which region that coordinate is in?**

It would seem like using a blocking method such as:

```
if(X < 100 && Z < 100){
     regionA();
} else if(X < 200 && Z < 200){
     regionB();
}
//and so on..
```

would be incredibly inefficient.

Is there any other way to check which region the coordinate is in?

Another example could be this:

Based on latitude and longitude, how could you find out which country a coordinate is in (or is it in the ocean, etc.)?

Comment: If it has three dimensions it is not a plane, it is a *cube*

Comment: With the way you have broken it up, it's very likely that your random numbers won't land in any of your 10 smaller chunks.

Comment: You'll only occupy all possible values in a 1-dimensional 1000 unit area with 10 divisions (lines). 2 dimensions would need 100 divisions (squares/planes) and 3 dimensions needs 1000 divisions (cubes) to fill the entire space. For example, where does 0, 0, 101 end up? and 0, 0, 201? And 100, 0, 201? etc.

Comment: My question is not pertaining to the dividing of the regions, my question is what is the best way to find which region a coordinate is in?

Comment: @user3344572 The problem is that your region divisions aren't clear. From what you've listed it sounds like you're only using the diagonal regions. You need to more fully explain the region divisions as it sounds like the ones Human listed don't exist.

Comment: Couple of further issues regarding your question, in any plane you have coordinates that increase in the positive range and/or the  negative range based on your direction of movement from the point of origin.  Based on your example you have given you appear to be assuming that x and z are only increasing on the positive scale and therefore only located in one quarter of the plane grid.

Also as Matthew pointed out is your y coordinate a factor in the region counting? or is the region only determined by the x,z plane alone.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since each region, so to speak, is 100 blocks wide, we can just use the hundreds value in the coordinates. I'm assuming you're dividing the plane into 100x100 regions.

```
int x; //Your coordinates here
int z;

double regionx = math.ceil(x/100);
double regionz = math.ceil(z/100);
```

You can use
    `regionx.intValue()` or `regionz.intValue()` if you need an int value return